# CodeIgniter: DB Insert returns '1' but nothing appears in the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a site I've been working on. Everything worked nicely until I reinstalled the operating systems. Now, after reinstalling everything, the site does work (PHP works, phpinfo() puts out all the needed components etc.), but the database queries are not working.

For example, when I try to add a new user to the database, I do this:

```
$new_user_insert_data = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
);

$insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_user_insert_data);
```

This worked before reinstalling the operating systems. $insert is '1' after doing the insert() call, but nothing appears in the database. Also, nothing can be retrieved from the database using get(). I've tried both mysql and mysqli, but neither works. What could be the cause here? I restored the same database I used before the OS reinstallation, but for some reason, the 'users' table did not import correctly so I had to re-create it manually.

Comment: make sure ... you are chekcing the same users database table..

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors - `$this->db->_error_message()`?

Comment: @Kami it causes this: "mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: simply write $this->db->insert('users', $new_user_insert_data); dont assign it to the variable

Comment: @plainjane It's no use.

Comment: When CI doesn’t throw you a DB error it is probably because you want to insert for example text in a column which only accepts integers. [reference](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/172216/#819308)

Comment: @plainjane I did say it that this used to work and I didn't change anything. It was only after re-installing the system that this stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

`$insert` will always display 1.

please `echo $this->db->affected_rows();`

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW GRANTS;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

run these query

```
Ref:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html
```